# Enabling mod_php on Ubuntu

Tags: apache

I'm trying to enable mod_php on Ubuntu.  I'm getting

```
/etc$ sudo a2enmod mod_php
ERROR: Module mod_php does not exist!
```

But I believe it's already installed from

```
etc$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-php5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 91 not upgraded.
```

Any advice?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 8):

I would try this command: `sudo a2enmod php5`

Also, please look here.  There's an extremely good chance you don't even *need* "a2enmod" to get things working:

http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.debian.php

http://chipersoft.com/p/Setting-up-a-LAMP-server-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

Did you try mod_php5? Haven't used ubuntu in a couple years but I think you can look at the module names in /etc/apache2/mods-available (and even symlink them to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled, which is pretty much what a2en does

Answer (score 0):

On Mageia5 you can enable it like this:

```
urpmi apache-mod_php
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Running this command, should install Apache 2.x and install the latest validated PHP and enable it as well. (Validated with Ubuntu).

```
sudo apt-get install apache php
```

If PHP is not installed, run with `php5.6` or `php7.0`  or `php7.1`  or `php7.2` instead.

```
sudo apt-get install apache php5.6
sudo apt-get install apache php7.0
sudo apt-get install apache php7.1
sudo apt-get install apache php7.2
```

You way want to checkout `ondrej/php` if your Ubuntu doesn't include the latest PHP version.